# TeamCity Cannot ping server exception

Tags: teamcity

Here is the summary of my setup;

- I have a TeamCity server installed on a windows machine it's on the node 192.168.10.20
- There is another VM on the node 192.168.8.235 that has a TeamCity agent on it. it should connect to the team city server.
- They're both connected to the same VPN network, meaning that both are on the same network and are accessible. There is no firewall!

And now I'm getting this weird error. I have no clue what could possibly have gone wrong.

```
[2015-02-06 13:06:52,749]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Call http://192.168.10.20:8087/RPC2 buildServer.registerAgent3: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: jetbrains.buildServer.CannotPingAgentException: Unable to ping agent Mac Build Server. Check firewall and/or try to specify 'ownAddress' in the agent configuration. Details: Agent 'Mac Build Server' cannot be accessed by any of the addresses: [192.168.8.235], (port 9090) 
[2015-02-06 13:06:52,750]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server is probably lost. Will be trying to restore it. Take a look at logs/teamcity-agent.log for details (unless you're using custom logging).
```

Also I have another question here, does this mean that central build server can't connect to this agent? Where is this exception getting thrown? On the agent machine or on the team city server? I can't imagine not being able to ping yourself.

Comment: This is the log from your Agent trying to get to the Server, right? Is the Server up? Can you ping from the Agent to the Server via the command prompt?

Comment: That's true, It's the team city log on the agent's VM. and Yes I can ping the team city server from agent's VM and other way around. That's why I'm clueless.

Comment: Any proxy servers or missing network config on the agent?

Comment: TeamCity requires both agent-server and server-agent communication. Your server cannot ping agent on address 192.168.8.235 port 9000. Ensure you don't have any firewall on agent VM and VM ports are open.

Comment: Ok so the issue was the way our company has setup the VPN, I could ping the agent from server but that was the only port forwarded. it wasn't firewall, we only had to forward 9090 on the server.